# Style was not found XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, styles

So I have my App.xaml :

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Fitness_App.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="WorkoutStyle" TargetType="Label">
              <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28"/>
              <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="BebasNeue"/>
              <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Wheat"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Here I declared a style GLOBALLY as far as I've read the microsoft documentation.However , when in another xaml file I do this:

```
 <Label Style= "{StaticResource WorkoutStyle}"
```

It says that WorkoutStyle could not be found.Any idea why?

Comment: Did u build it?

Answer (score 1):

Declaration is correct. Just Remove obj and bin of targeted project and do a rebuild.
This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="WorkoutStyle" TargetType="Label">
          <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28"/>
          <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Wheat"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This line is not good

```
 <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="BebasNeue"/>
```

Your FontFamily is wrong look here for an example , change it with your font

```
 <Style x:Key="NormalFont" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="NunitoSans-Regular.ttf#NunitoSans-Regular.ttf"/>
</Style>
```

Explaned here
https://www.serkanseker.com/xamarin-forms-custom-font-family/

Comment: Any update on this question , did you solved it